# Why computing P(x,D) is simpler than P(x|D) in exponential bayesian networks?

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, exponential-family, variational-bayes

I am reading [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.orchid.ac.uk/eprints/40/1/fox_vbtut.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjFx-7v5YDOAhUGsJQKHV5_DEMQFggqMAI&usg=AFQjCNGMXcxGPdfQMThMGn93GWgciRmIiA&sig2=yXzznXP-xKtDV4Lzal10DA) tutorial on variational inference and wonder why the statement in the question title which is mentioned on page 3 is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in Bayesian analyses, you start off with the likelihood and priors, which directly yields the *unnormalized* joint distribution. So let's say $\Theta$ is the set of all parameters. Since the likelihood is not always *equal to* the density but *proportional*, it is clear that $$L\left(\Theta|y\right)p\left(\Theta\right) \propto p\left(y,\Theta\right).$$ But oftentimes integrating out $\Theta$ will be hard. This is why it's better to work with $p\left(y,\Theta\right)$ than $p\left(\Theta|y\right)$.

In short, sometimes you won't be able to do the integration.

Comment: Then what is the need for emphasising on the "exponential family" part?

Comment: Because you need to take the logarithm and then take the expectation in variational inference. If it's exponential family, algebra becomes much easier.

Answer (score 1):

To compute P(x|D) you typically need P(D), which requires integrating x out.

Comment: Then what is the need for emphasising on the "exponential family" part?